# Generating a PDF report in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, reporting, rcp

I've been handed the task (not sure if i like it or not) of generating a PDF export in an eclipse RCP app. I'm looking for a framework with as little effort as possible I can pass in a pojo model and some kind of template and presto.. get a PDF report back. I've taken a look at BIRT and I'm sure it offers that functionality just was hard to read through all the stuff does anyone have a tool they use to do this that is really easy or any ideas of how to move forward? Thanks - Duncan krebs

Comment: Another option besides iText is Apache PDFBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most widely used framework for this purpose is [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com/). Be sure to check out the [terms of use](http://www.itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/index.php).

Answer (score 4):

iText is great for generating all kinds of PDFs, but If you're going to do reports, then I have to recommend [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports).

Also, you can use [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/index.php?q=project/ireport) to simplify the design of your jasper reports.

Answer (score 0):

I use iText with Spring.  A good example can be found in Springs tutorial at [Spring pdf](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-document)